# Opensource cross-platform app development IDE?

Tags: android, ios, windows

I am a Java web application developer. I would like to develop my web application as app, so I need to know if there is any open-source tool or IDE available for cross-platform app development.

Suggest me any open-source application which is used to develop apps for all OSes, for example: Android, iOS, and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There is no universal solution* (yet).

But you can find ways to share code and patterns between different platforms. And making the decision as to what tools to use for cross-platform app development is not something that can be easily done unless you have reasonable experience in the platforms you are targeting. Also, the more platforms you do want to target, the harder this problem becomes.

You mention you have a web application.  My initial advice will be to build a mobile app (on one platform) that hosts your website in a browser control. That's often the simplest starting point for converting a website into an app - but it will likely come with some limitations.

No you want to customize that into a tailored app?  Next piece of advice would be to go learn Android development, since your Java skills (and perhaps your code) will transition nicely.

Got your java website ported to Android?  Well, you are on your own on how to get to all the other platforms, but you'll have the mobile experience to make the decision soundly.

Here are some ideas to get you started:

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) and [ItelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) are good starts for IDEs that target cross-platform Java/Android development. [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) is a modified version of IntelliJ.

[Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) for cross-development on all the different mobile platforms.

[QT](http://www.qt.io/) for cross-development on mobile, Mac, and Windows.

And I should probably mention [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) as well. Just because.

[Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx) (still in Beta, but available for download) is targeting more than just Windows these days: iOS and Android. Eventually will be the platform for creating apps that run on all flavors of Windows (modern, win32, phone, xbox, etc...)

And Windows Phone [might be running Android and iOS apps sooner than later](http://www.fastcompany.com/3045720/fast-feed/heres-how-windows-10-plans-to-hit-1-billion-devices-in-3-years).

None of these tools above are a complete solution, but in any shop that makes cross-platform code, you'll likely find some subset of the above.